# Accent in Regular Expression in Java

Tags: java, regex, hibernate-validator

I'd like to use Hibernate Validator to validate some columns. The problem, as I understand, is that the \w marker in java doesn't accept letters with accents on them.

Is there any way that I could write the regexp so that words like Relatório could be validated (i wouldn't want to write all letters with accents between brackets, because I expect to be writing this regexp in a lot of columns)?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The [Java regex documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) has a section on Unicode categories (search for "Classes for Unicode blocks and categories"). If you're just looking for letters, I think `\p{L}` is the category you want.

Comment: Amazing!! `\p{L}` matches only letters in any language, even accentuated ones! It matches: `文字`, `символы`, `字符`, `tähemärki` but it doesnt `♥♦♣♠•◘○◙♂♀♪♫☼►◄` or numbers. This is perfect!

Comment: @Kuriel Add a `+` or `*` to the end and it works perfectly well.  What you're testing is matching a single character.

Answer (score 16):

I had more luck with:

```
\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+
```

In java I use the following method:

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.text.Normalizer.Form;

public static String removeAccents(String text) {
    return text == null ? null :
        Normalizer.normalize(text, Form.NFD)
            .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
}
```

Comment: This method removes all sort of accents perfectly.
Turns `"á à ä ê ç ü ï ñ"` into `"a a a e c u i n"`. It normalizes awesomely.